# Can't import UserSerializer into another serializers.py

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have not been able to figure this out.

I'm trying to import my UserSerializer() from 'accounts' app, so that I can use nest it within my CommentSerializer() in 'comments' app.

If I try to nest another serializer such as LikeSerializer() from 'likes' app, there's no problems.

If you notice in the comments.serializers.py, I can uncomment the LikeSerializer parts, and comment the UserSerializer, and no errors.

But once I uncomment the UserSerializer(), I'm hit with `ImportError: cannot import name UserSerializer`.

My folder structure:

```
/apps
  /accounts
    serializers.py
  /comments
    serializers.py
```

**accounts.serializers.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import update_session_auth_hash
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import User, ProfilePic

from ..memories.serializers import MemorySerializer

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    memories = MemorySerializer(many=True,read_only=True)
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=False)
    # password2 = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=False)

    class Meta:

        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'created_at', 'relation', 'password', 'memories',)
        read_only_fields = ('created_at',)

        def create(self, validated_data):

            return User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)

        def update(self, instance, validated_data):

            instance.email = validated_data.get('email', instance.email)
            instance.first_name = validated_data.get('first_name', instance.first_name)
            isntance.last_name = validated_data.get('last_name', instance.last_name)
            instance.relation = validated_data.get('relation', instance.relation)

            instance.save()

            password = validated_data.get('password', instance.password)
            # password2 = validated_data.get('password2', instance.password2)

            # if password and password2 and password == password2:

            #   instance.set_password(password)
            #   instance.save()

            update_session_auth_hash(self.context.get('request'), instance)

            return instance
```

**comments.serializers.py

```
from .models import Comment

from ..accounts.serializers import UserSerializer
# from ..likes.serializers import LikeSerializer

from rest_framework import serializers

class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    author = UserSerializer()   
    # likes = LikeSerializer(many=True,read_only=True)

    # sub_comments = serializers.CommentSerializer()

    class Meta:

        model = Comment
        fields = ('id','author','memory','content','sub_comments', 'likes','created_at')
        read_only = ('memory','created_at',)
        depth = 1
```

**traceback

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x1037e1cf8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/bchuey/.environments/dm_lin/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/bchuey/.environments/dm_lin/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 116, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/Users/bchuey/.environments/dm_lin/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 426, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/Users/bchuey/.environments/dm_lin/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 75, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/Users/bchuey/.environments/dm_lin/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/Users/bchuey/.environments/dm_lin/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    for pattern in resolver.url_patterns:
  File "/Users/bchuey/.environments/dm_lin/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 33, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Users/bchuey/.environments/dm_lin/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 417, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/Users/bchuey/.environments/dm_lin/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 33, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Users/bchuey/.environments/dm_lin/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 410, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/bchuey/Documents/digital_memorials/dm_you_lin/src/digital_memorial/urls.py", line 19, in <module>
    from apps.accounts.views import UserViewSet, ProfilePicViewSet, LoginView
  File "/Users/bchuey/Documents/digital_memorials/dm_you_lin/src/apps/accounts/views.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .serializers import UserSerializer, ProfilePicSerializer
  File "/Users/bchuey/Documents/digital_memorials/dm_you_lin/src/apps/accounts/serializers.py", line 5, in <module>
    from ..memories.serializers import MemorySerializer
  File "/Users/bchuey/Documents/digital_memorials/dm_you_lin/src/apps/memories/serializers.py", line 3, in <module>
    from ..comments.serializers import CommentSerializer
  File "/Users/bchuey/Documents/digital_memorials/dm_you_lin/src/apps/comments/serializers.py", line 4, in <module>
    from ..accounts.serializers import UserSerializer
ImportError: cannot import name UserSerializer
```

Comment: Why dont you add the app folder to your python path and then remove all leading .. before your imports

Answer (score 0):

Append the 'apps' folder to your python path and try importing from accounts.serializers ? You can also remove all leading .. from your other imports (provided they are a subdirectory of apps)

** accounts.serializers.py

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/Users/bchuey/Documents/digital_memorials/dm_you_lin/src/apps") 

from django.contrib.auth import update_session_auth_hash
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import User, ProfilePic

from memories.serializers import MemorySerializer

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    memories = MemorySerializer(many=True,read_only=True)
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=False)
    password2 = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=False)

    class Meta:

        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'created_at', 'relation', 'password', 'memories',)
        read_only_fields = ('created_at',)

        def create(self, validated_data):
            return User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)

        def update(self, instance, validated_data):
            instance.email = validated_data.get('email', instance.email)
            instance.first_name = validated_data.get('first_name', instance.first_name)
            instance.last_name = validated_data.get('last_name', instance.last_name)
            instance.relation = validated_data.get('relation', instance.relation)
            instance.save()

            password = validated_data.get('password', instance.password)
            password2 = validated_data.get('password2', instance.password2)

            if password and password2 and password == password2:
                instance.set_password(password)
                instance.save()

            update_session_auth_hash(self.context.get('request'), instance)
            return instance
```

** comments.serializers.py

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/Users/bchuey/Documents/digital_memorials/dm_you_lin/src/apps") 

from .models import Comment

from accounts.serializers import UserSerializer
from likes.serializers import LikeSerializer

from rest_framework import serializers

class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    author = UserSerializer()   
    likes = LikeSerializer(many=True,read_only=True)
    sub_comments = serializers.CommentSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('id','author','memory','content','sub_comments', 'likes','created_at')
        read_only = ('memory','created_at',)
        depth = 1
```

Comment: Ok. So I implemented your suggestion. Still not able to import UserSerializer. The `.../src/apps` was appended to syspath and is line2.

Comment: Are there any errors in your User Serializer class?